# matching query does not exist in database

Tags: django, django-models, google-bigquery, pycharm, ipython

whenever I try to get my list of items in query I am getting this error

from django.db import models

## Create your models here.

```
class ToDo(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    
class Item(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDo, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    complete = models.BooleanField()
        
    
    def __str__(self, text = text):
        return self.text
```

that line i am executing in my pycharm terminal

```
In [3]: lt = ToDo.objects.get(id = 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DoesNotExist                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-23a0e6ec0ffa> in <module>
----> 1 lt = ToDo.objects.get(id = 1)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py in manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     83         def create_method(name, method):
     84             def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 85                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
     86             manager_method.__name__ = method.__name__
     87             manager_method.__doc__ = method.__doc__

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    433             return clone._result_cache[0]
    434         if not num:
--> 435             raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
    436                 "%s matching query does not exist." %
    437                 self.model._meta.object_name

DoesNotExist: ToDo matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: The error seems to be very obvious? There simply is no `ToDo` which has `id = 1`...

Comment: To @AbdulAzizBarkat point, I'd try running `print(ToDo.objects.filter(id=1))` and see what comes up. If it returns null/empty, you'll know the issue is you don't have an object with `id=1`.